# JS formatnumber/addcommas not working

Tags: javascript, wordpress, number-formatting

I am using wordpress and I have a few plugins that I have used to try and assist with some pagespeed score increases. That being said I have done some customization on the site and when I do so I lost the addcommas function it seems to the range slider I have on the bar. I cannot get it to show the commas with the numbers any longer. It is just showing the dollar sign. I have tried disabling the plugins, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

The site is www.cjhitch.com

Here's the slider

```
<div>

<div id="slider" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">

<i class="bulleft"></i>
<i class="bulright"></i>
<div id="slider-min">

    $100,000

</div>
<div id="slider-max">

    $2,000,000

</div>
<div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-slider-range-min"></div>
<span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all div-cover" tabindex="0">

   <input id="amount" type="text" readonly=""></input>
</span>

</div>
</div>
```

The equal signs aren't part of the code, I had to use it to get them to show up.

Here is the JS

```
<script>
 $(function() {
 $( "#slider" ).slider({
  range: 'min',
  value: 250000,
  min: 100000,
  max: 2000000,
  step: 1000,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
   $("#amount").val("$" + addCommas(ui.value));
    $("#result1").val("$" + formatNumber(Math.round(ui.value*.033 - 2799)));
    $("#result2").val("$" + formatNumber(Math.round(ui.value*.06 -5299)));
    $("#result3").val("$" + formatNumber(Math.round(ui.value*.06 -3799)));
  }
 });

function formatNumber (num) {
  return num.toString().replace(/(d)(?=(d{3})+(?!d))/g, "$1,")
}

console.info(formatNumber(2665));      // 2,665
console.info(formatNumber(102665));    // 102,665
console.info(formatNumber(111102665)); // 111,102,665

$('#amount').val( "$" +          formatNumber($("#slider").slider("value"))).detach().appendTo('.ui-slider-handle');
$('.ui-slider-handle').prepend('<i class="fa fa-usd"></i>');

function addCommas(nStr)
{
  nStr += '';
  x = nStr.split('.');
  x1 = x[0];
  x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
  var rgx = /(d+)(d{3})/;
  while (rgx.test(x1)) {
    x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
}
  return x1 + x2;
}
});
</script>
```

As you can see, I've tried two different kinds, number format and add commas. They have both functioned at a time in the past, but now something seems to be "sanitizing" it.

If anyone knows how to fix this, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Could you perhaps reduce the amount of code in your question to the minimal code that reproduces the issue? Maybe just the addCommas function and a couple of input examples are enough for the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion this is because ui.value does not contain dots(.) and you do not split it.
Try this.

```
function addCommas(nStr){
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split( /(?=(?:...)*$)/);
    return x;
}
```

of course you can use this function on results for example:

```
$("#result1").val("$" + addCommas(formatNumber(Math.round(ui.value*.033 - 2799))));
```

Comment: This function worked perfectly on chrome and firefox. Unfortunately on Safari, it is adding a comma to the end as well. http://i.imgur.com/jWqcRiV.png

Comment: try this
/(?=(?:...)+$)/

Comment: That worked, thank you so much! I was wracking my brain over that all day yesterday before I decided to ask for help!

Answer (score 0):

There's [Intl.NumberFormat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) for the exact task you are trying to perform. So you might better use it, as it does what it should very convenient. The only downside here is Safari that doesn't support it as the only browser,  but you can use this package:

https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js

to polyfill.

Here's a copy from mozilla's documentation I've linked above on the usage:

```
var number = 123456.789;

// request a currency format
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(number));
// → 123.456,79 €

// the Japanese yen doesn't use a minor unit
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('ja-JP', { style: 'currency', currency: 'JPY' }).format(number));
// → ￥123,457

// limit to three significant digits

    console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { maximumSignificantDigits: 3 }).format(number));
// → 1,23,000
```